# Is it possible to query Firebase on emoji characters?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, emoji

I would like to perform a firebase query from swift which natively supports emojis. However I am noticing odd behavior when performing queries ending in `~` where emoji related results are being skipped. Below is a sample of the query I would like to perform. Where the start value is some name, and the end value is that name concatenated with `~`. I’m noticing that when the name ends in an emoji the name with the emoji is not being returned in the query. Is it possible to perform a query on emojis while using The Firebase Real Time Database like one can in [Firestore](https://twitter.com/CodingDoug/status/961302822997213184)?

```
Database.database()
    .reference(withPath: "TagIDs")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "name")
    .queryStarting(atValue: startValue)
    .queryEnding(atValue: endValue)
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    …
```

> Input name = “home”
>
> expected output = “home”
>
> actual output: The snapshot is empty

Comment: If you edit the question to show the actual inputs and outputs that are different than what you expect, it might be easier to see what's going on here.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your help I added in the suggested edits, I hope it helps please let me know if there is more I can provide to help thank you.

Comment: What are your startValue and endValue?  We should be able to reproduce the problem exactly as you're seeing it.  Right now, there's just not enough information.  It's best if you remove all variable and use hard-coded strings.  Also show the contents of the database, along with the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it seems like you're searching with:

```
Database.database()
    .reference(withPath: "TagIDs")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "name")
    .queryStarting(atValue: "home")
    .queryEnding(atValue: "home~")
```

And then expecting to get `"home"` as a result. But  is actually after `~` in the Unicode spec, so your query ends before .

To get the full range of `TagIDs` values starting with `"home"` end the query at `"home\uf8ff"`, with `\u{f8ff}` being the escape for the last code point in Unicode.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Frank! That fixed it! One small note in Swift it is `\u{f8ff}`